# Update a table's newly added column with matching records SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've recently added a new foreign key constraint (`ProjectID`) to my `Invoice` table and I'm trying to update the `Invoice` table so that the foreign key matches with a given set of records.

Using the following query, I'm able to find the matching records.

```
SELECT 
    IV.InvoiceID, TA.ProjectID 
FROM 
    Invoices IV
JOIN 
    TimeEntries TE on TE.InvoiceId = IV.InvoiceID
JOIN 
    Tasks TA ON TE.TaskID = TA.TaskID
```

I'm thinking the right way is to use a cursor and iterate through all records in the `Tasks` table, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @ForeignKey int

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT IV.InvoiceID, TA.ProjectID FROM Invoices IV
JOIN TimeEntries TE on TE.InvoiceId = IV.InvoiceID
JOIN Tasks TA ON TE.TaskID = TA.TaskID

OPEN C

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @ForeignKey

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE Invoices
    SET ProjectID = @ForeignKey
    WHERE InvoiceID = ??? (Need matching ID)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should never think, "A cursor is probably the best way to do this." SQL Server is built to handle sets of data, not iterate through data. Cursors were a concession to programmers who kept demanding them, a solution to some problems which are no longer an issue because of advances in SQL implementations, and to handle **extremely** rare cases in which a set-based approach is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a cursor for this:

```
UPDATE IV
    SET ProjectId = TA.ProjectID 
    FROM Invoices IV JOIN
         TimeEntries TE 
         ON TE.InvoiceId = IV.InvoiceID JOIN
         Tasks TA ON TE.TaskID = TA.TaskID;
```